# Update ros version

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! this might sound like a silly question, but how do I update my ros version from indigo to kinetic?
I plan to move from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04, but I do not know if after that I have to remove my indigo version and install kinetic, or just by installing kinetic automatically removes any older version.

Thanks a lot and sotty for the silly question

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270878/update-ros-version/) by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2017-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you going to update your Ubuntu version to 16.04? Are you going to use the packet manager to upgrade your OS or would you rather do a clean install from installation media?

Whenever you start from a fresh new Ubuntu 16.04 installation, you will only get the option to install ROS Kinetic (or higher), because ROS Indigo does not support Ubuntu 16.04. (Please see #q245288, if you really want to install Kinetic and Indigo in parallel.)
If you perform an OS upgrade through the Ubuntu packet manager, then your packet manager will supposedly remove ROS Indigo automatically unless you installed ROS from source. The packet manager should know, that the ROS Indigo packages will no longer be compatible with the new OS version.

For me, a fresh new Ubuntu installation always appeared to be the safest way to upgrade from ROS Indigo to ROS Kinetic, so I have never tried to use the automatic OS upgrade.

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2017-09-15**:
yes, I am just updating it and it told that it was going to eliminate ros-indigo-desktop-full so I did not have to do it my self, I did not know that. I am updating it from de packet manager.
Thanks a lot